# Silex: populate form with entered data after invalid submit

Tags: twig, silex

After the user submits a (uncomplete) form, I want the form to show the already entered data + an error message.

Using this code, the form is empty after submitting the form:

```
$request = $app['request'];

$form = $app['form.factory']->createBuilder('form')
    ->add('name', 'text', array( 'label' => 'Ihre Name:'))
    ->add('comment', 'text', array('constraints' => new Assert\Length(array('min' => 15))))
    ->getForm();

$twig_context = array('form' => $form->createView());

$form->handleRequest($request);

if ($form->isValid()) {
    $data = $form->getData();
    return 'valid!';
    // Send form...
} else {
    // display the form
    return $app['twig']->render('contact.html.twig', $twig_context);
}
```

Twig-template:

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
{{ form_widget(form) }}
<div>
    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</div>
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create the form view last, (could be right before you render your template). In your case, the view is created before the data from `Request` is applied.

This:

```
$twig_context = array('form' => $form->createView());

$form->handleRequest($request);
```

Should be:

```
$form->handleRequest($request);
```

And your render method should be:

```
return $app['twig']->render('contact.html.twig', 
    array(
        'form' => $form->createView()
    )
);
```